# href in css link won't load from previous directory

Tags: php, html, css

So currently I'm a starting off web developer. I don't have much experience with how websites "should" be formatted. I am trying my hardest though to keep everything as organized as possible and I'm trying to think ahead before I program anything large ( ie: a website with a number of pages that may need to be updated in the future. ).

So I decided to learn php so I can make websites more update-able and workable with a vast array of projects. So, I'm starting simple and seeing if I can keep all css in one spot so that it would be easy for any page to load from. Loading these cascading sheets I made a function in PHP to find their directory and then to load the actual php. BUT when I load the css from the direct path it doesn't seem to actually load. It actually seems that it is trying to load from the current directory as a relative path to the full path that I have. Thus problems of "file url forbidden" and what not.

I've tried manually inserting the .css 's path, and using my php code -- But neither work.

My php code looks like this

```
<?php // This gives us the current path needed.
$direct = __DIR__;
$dirList = explode( "\\", $direct );
$length = count( $dirList );
$curPath = "";
$curPart = "";
for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++ )
{
    $curPart = $dirList[ $i ];
    $curPath .= $curPart . "/";
    if ( $curPart == "mSite" )
        break;
}
$curPath = str_replace("\"", "",  $curPath );
?>
```

And my linker looks like this

```
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/<?php echo ($curPath."css_sheets/navBar_sheet.css"); ?>" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/unServ/New Testing/css_sheets"/>
```

Yeah, my code may definitely not look good, but I'm just starting out. Any help appreciated! I've looked all over the web and on this site but I just could not figure out how to word it properly - or no one seems to really have had this problem before.

Ps: I've tried using "SRC" instead of "HREF" and i've tried putting the "/" before the path but none of its worked.

Comment: what does `$curPath` echoes?

Comment: So you wish to load the CSS and then publish whatever you have stored in your database? I recommand just loading everything at ones instead of having to load, load and load spreadsheets throughout looking at the website... Use root folder adresses like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../foldername/spreadsheet.css">`

Comment: Roullie, $curPath echos 
/C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/unServ/UniServerZ/www/mSite/css_sheets/navBar_sheet.css" --- The current direct Path.
@FriedBitz I tried it like so : "/mSite/css_sheets/navBar_sheet.css" but no luck.

Comment: Okai, first off, all your files are in one root folder, right? By adding dot infront of the / you take it from the current folder... by adding two dots, you go up one folders... so lets say you have a folder named css_sheets in your website folder... you go like this... `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css_sheets/navBar_sheet.css">` if you are in a subfolder allready you just add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css_sheets/navBar_sheet.css">`

Comment: So by what I understand you Add one period for every folder deep you are from the folder you are trying to reach? So let's say i was in folder "neat" of list "example/file/directory/neat/"  would I use three periods to access folder "example"?  Also, where would I find an article if possible on this subject? Thank you much, friedbitz.

Comment: What they said. Also, your bottommost link doesn't even contain the name of the css file, it ends in the directory.

Comment: Thanks every one for the help. I finally ended up finding an article that really helped me out to understand what you were all trying to tell me.
--- http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Comment: If you answered your own question, either post the answer and mark it as the accepted answer or delete it. We don't do "[SOLVED]" here.

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with this forums ( or question site ) way of operation. I'm going to read the guidelines to make sure I don't make any more faults. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article entry from css-tricks.com answers my question perfectly about relative paths.

> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
>   Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
>   Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
>   there (and so on...) To move forward, just start with the first
>   subdirectory and keep moving forward

Quoted from the article:
 http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/